# Parse Xamarin SDK significantly bloats app size for iOS apps

Tags: ios, generics, parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin for building my app. Before I integrated Parse in my app, my binary size (Release build, all optimizations, LLVM, armv7 and arm64) was 23MB. I added the Parse Xamarin SDK (using Xamarin components) to my app and then added one .cs file to represent a model on Parse. After this my app size almost doubled to 42MB, (i.e. increased roughly 10MB per architecture).

My questions:

1. Why is there such a huge app bloat?
2. Is there some way for me to get the app size back down to a reasonable level?

**Additional details:**

I used `symbols` to get the information from the binary on what symbols are using this additional space. (Note: This is for 1 architecture only)

Get all functions from the System namespace:

```
symbols TestApp |grep FUNC | grep 'System' | grep -v 'Xamarin' | awk '{ print $3; }' | sed 's/)$//' | awk 'BEGIN{sum = 0} { val = sprintf("%d\n", $0); sum += val; } END {print sum; }'
```

*Before adding the parse dll*: 963KB

*After adding the parse dll*: 4.5MB

The Parse.ios.dll is only 212K. However when compiled it adds 3.6MB of code to the final binary:

```
symbols TestApp |grep FUNC | egrep 'Parse|\[PF' |  awk '{ print $3; }' | sed 's/)$//' | awk 'BEGIN{sum = 0} { val = sprintf("%d\n", $0); sum += val; } END {print sum; }'
3639308
```

The added functions are things along the lines of:

> 0x000104f4 (   0x260)
>   System_Array_InternalArray__ICollection_CopyTo_T_T___int [FUNC,
>   LENGTH, NameDwarfMIPSLinkage, MangledNameNList, Merged, NList, Dwarf,
>   FunctionStarts] 0x000108f8 (   0x64c)
>   System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_intptr_System_WeakReference_System_Collections_ICollection_CopyTo_System_Array_int
>   [FUNC, LENGTH, NameDwarfMIPSLinkage, MangledNameNList, Merged, NList,
>   Dwarf, FunctionStarts]

So it looks like a lot this code is due to generics being compiled to native code. Is there some way to reduce to amount of code bloat caused by generics?

Answer (score 1):

Enable the managed linker for all assemblies.

In the project's iOS Build options, set "Link behavior" to "All assemblies"

More information about the linker: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/

More general build information (including how to minimize app size) is explained here: [Advanced iOS Build Mechanics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIDI2d86zTE)

Comment: I already do that. I've watched the video as well, but there isn't much else than what you mentioned already.